# Changing linespacing in tikz node text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Considering the following beamer/tikz code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,shapes,matrix,backgrounds,arrows,shadows,
   positioning,fit,automata,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,bending,quotes,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Server Operating Systems}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw=none,shade,align=center,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=4cm,
    top color=blue!40,
    bottom color=blue!5,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    blur shadow={shadow blur steps=2}
    ] at (3,1) (a) {\sffamily\bfseries\huge Windows\\
    \sffamily\bfseries\huge \vspace*{3mm} Server};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can one change the line spacing for the text i.e. space between Windows and Server (in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary measurement after `\\`, like `\\[1ex]` or `\\[1mm]`. If you need this in multiple nodes, an alternative solution (more automatic) might be better. But for one instance, this is a quick fix.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,shapes,matrix,backgrounds,arrows,shadows,
   positioning,fit,automata,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,bending,quotes,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Server Operating Systems}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw=none,shade,align=center,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=4cm,
    top color=blue!40,
    bottom color=blue!5,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge,
    blur shadow={shadow blur steps=2}
    ] at (3,1) (a) {Windows\\[1mm] Server};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way how you define fonts for text in node is wrong, so the spacing consider normal text size instead of huge, as you expected. try the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
%\usepackage{fontspec}% commented that I can use pdftex, it also should work with xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, automata, backgrounds, bending, 
            calc, decorations.text, decorations.pathreplacing,
            fit, matrix, positioning, quotes,
            shadows, shapes,shadows.blur}

  \begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Server Operating Systems}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[draw=none,shade,align=center,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=4cm,
    top color=blue!40,
    bottom color=blue!5,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    blur shadow={shadow blur steps=2,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge}  % <---
    ] at (3,1) (a) {Windows\\ Server}; % <---
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Changes in comparison with your MWE  are indicated by % <---
[image]

**Edit:** if the normal distance between lines is not what you looking for, than you can change this for example by

```
\node[draw=none,shade,align=center,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=4cm,
    top color=blue!40,
    bottom color=blue!5,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    blur shadow={shadow blur steps=2,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge}  % <---
    ] at (3,1) (a) {Windows\\[5ex] Server}; % <---
```

and obtain

[image]

You aren't very clear what you like to obtain. Probably will help you to read TikZ manual,  section *Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text* on page 223 (recent version)

Comment: But still it doesn't provide me control over line spacing.

Comment: What of control? Naw you have clean normal situation. If this is not acceptable, than you now can change for amount like `\\[<change od vertical distance>]` ...